# Electrostatics equations

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

Coulomb's Law gives us the static electrical force $F,$ exerted by a point charge $Q_1$ on another point charge $Q_2$ in terms of $r $, the distance between them.

$$F =\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

However, there is another formula that is also known as the coulomb's law that is similar to the equation above.

$$F =k\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{ r^2} $$

What is the difference between the two? isnt both are looking for the force exert from one charge to the other?

In addition, by looking at the equation how do we differentiate which force are we looking for in the equation? Is $F$ the force from $Q_1$ act on $Q_2$ or vice versa? It would still be $F$ since both $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ is multiple together

thanks

Comment: Hint: action-reaction.  Moreover, the equation is vectorial so if you know the sign of the charges and the direction vector of $\vec F$ you can work it out easily.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, just expressed in terms of different constants. $k=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} $

By Newton's Third Law, the forces of each on the other are equal in magnitude, so this formula gives you the magnitude of either force.

Comment: ah ty. It make sense now. How would we differentiate which force we're looking for in the giving equation?

Comment: According to Newton's 3rd Law, both force would be of the same magnitude and opposite in direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two equations in the SI system of units because in that system of units $k = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}$ by definition.

There are many other systems which are in use or have been used in the past and for one of them $k=1$ by definition. One such system is called the [Gaussian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) and unit of charge is called the statcoulomb (statC), electrostatic unit (esu) or the franklin (Fr) with $1 \;\rm C = 3 \times 10^9 \,statC$.

Without assigning a sign to the charges your equations give the magnitude of the force on each of the charge which by Newton's third law must be equal.

For point charges the direction of the forces must along the line joining the two charges and the directions of the equal magnitude forces are assigned by remembering that like charges repel each other and unlike charges attract each other.